# Convert entire column with time values (hh:mm:ss) to text time (hh:mm)

Tags: excel

I have a column filled with time values `hh:mm:ss` in Sheet1. It is right aligned by default. I need to copy it to Sheet2 and convert it to hh:mm in text format which would be left aligned. I am using the following code:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value
```

now time values appears in Sheet2 as numbers e.g. 0.38745

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    DoEvents  
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = Format(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value, "hh:mm")
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select
Loop
```

After finishing the loop, time values are shown as `hh:mm` and these are left aligned. I want to replace this loop with a fast code because I have a large number of files to process.

Comment: There is no reason to convert to text just to change the alignment.  You can merely set `range.horizontalalignment = xlleft`.  Is there some other reason you want it as text?

Comment: I am not doing it just for alignment. I need it in text form to use it in other excel files. I have mentioned alignment here just to emphasize my requirement in text form. Data in text form will align to left. Sorry if it has diverted your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert the data to a properly formatted text string first, and then paste it as text.

For example (and note that I never use `Select` and fully qualify the worksheet/range references).

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyTime()
    Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
    Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim V, W, I As Long
    
Set wsCopyFrom = Worksheets("sheet9")
Set wsCopyTo = Worksheets("sheet10")

I = 0
With wsCopyFrom
    V = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    For Each W In V
        I = I + 1
        V(I, 1) = Format(W, "hh:mm")
    Next W
End With

With wsCopyTo
    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(V)) = V
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. My code is already working for me. I just want to replace loop with a faster code because looping a big number of cells is slow. Your code also contains a loop. Please try something else without a loop.

Comment: @sanjaynagpal Did you try the code I provided? It should be **much** faster than looping cells.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I have just checked it and your code is much faster than me. Please tell me do I need to use Set wsCopyFrom = Nothing at the end?

Comment: @sanjaynagpal Not necessary in VBA

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a code-based solution exactly, but there are various add-ons you can get for excel which include features like this. I use [ASAP Utilites](https://www.asap-utilities.com/), and it has hundreds of really useful tools (plus it's free).
In the ASAP example I know there's one tool for 'Convert cells to their formatted value' which takes all the formatted values of cells in the sheet and outputs them as a text value within the same cell. You could copy your data across, adjust the formatting so it looks how you want it to, then just use that one button to fix the values.

NB I am not affiliated with ASAP Utilities in any way. I just enjoy it and recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, actually this code is a part of big code and so I need a solution in code form only.